# SQL query return null and wrong information

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When I run this query it gives me the wrong information from the table. Also `PreviousRecord` column gets null value returns. I can't find the problem. Query returns data from tables shown below.

It shows me null value of 1 column.

I want [buyer], [style], [process] column wise summation.

This is the query I run:

```
DECLARE @section varchar(255)
DECLARE @form_date date

SET @section = 'Sewing'
SET @form_date = '2022-03-20'

SELECT        
    tbl_style_info.buyer, tbl_style_info.style, 
    tbl_style_info.process, 
    tbl_buyer_order_info.order_quantity, 
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(sew_floor_receive.rcv_quantity), 0) 
     FROM sew_floor_receive 
     WHERE sew_floor_receive.sew_rcv_date < @form_date 
       AND sew_floor_receive.section = @section 
       AND sew_floor_receive.style = tbl_style_info.style) AS PreviousRecord,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(sew_floor_receive.rcv_quantity), 0) 
     FROM sew_floor_receive 
     WHERE sew_floor_receive.sew_rcv_date = @form_date 
       AND sew_floor_receive.section = @section 
       AND sew_floor_receive.style = tbl_style_info.style) AS TodayRecord
FROM            
    sew_floor_receive 
INNER JOIN
    tbl_style_info ON sew_floor_receive.style = tbl_style_info.style 
                   AND sew_floor_receive.process = tbl_style_info.process 
INNER JOIN
    tbl_buyer_order_info ON sew_floor_receive.style = tbl_buyer_order_info.style
WHERE 
    sew_floor_receive.sew_rcv_date = @form_date 
    AND sew_floor_receive.section = @section
```

Comment: Table aliases will make the query easier to read.  Even so, I find it hard to understand what you are trying to get.  I see the SUM(sew_floor_receive.rcv_quantity).  Are you trying to multiple the rcv_quantity by the number of records in the sew_floor_receive table?  If not, then perhaps those are aggregated in a derived table and then joined.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sew_floor_receive](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [sew_rcv_date] [date] NULL,
 [section] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [style] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [process] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [color] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [size] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [rcv_quantity] [int] NULL,
 [rcv_by_section] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [remarks] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [cretetime] [datetime] NULL,
 [updatetime] [datetime] NULL)

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_style_info](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [buyer] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [section] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [style] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [process] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [status] [bit] NULL,
 [last_process] [bit] NULL,
 [create_time] [date] NULL
)

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_buyer_info](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [buyer] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [address] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

Comment: I added three table query. Can you tell me why null value comes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer cannot guarantee without the real data set.
But try to use aliases while using the same tables again and again. specially to your **sew_floor_receive** table and refer that alias correctly

Ex;

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(sew_floor_receive.rcv_quantity), 0) 
     FROM sew_floor_receive sfr
     WHERE sfr.sew_rcv_date < @form_date 
       AND sfr.section = @section 
       AND sfr.style = tbl_style_info.style)  AS PreviousRecord,
FROM            
    sew_floor_receive sfrmain
```

Otherwise, I cannot see any issue in the query.

Sometimes I am experiencing these types of issues with null values. But that depends on the Database types.

> New comment =======================

I checked your issue and it works for me.

[image: Test result]

But you missed a one table ([tbl_buyer_order_info]). So, I removed that link from my inner join. at the same time, without a proper dataset, it is really difficult to understand your problem,

If you can give us a SQL dump (at least with dummy) from your database, hope we can fix this issue.

Anyway, I have a few suggestions for you:

1. Use allies for tables to reduce the conflicts between fields
2. Use trim() with String fields
3. **Check your DB set as a case sensitive or case insensitive**
4. Always keep the same data type and lengths for your fields that you're going to link
   ex: style nvarchar(255) @ style_table and style nvarchar(50) @ floe_received table.
5. Always try to map with primary keys instead of using normal fields
   ex: sew_floor_receive.style = tbl_style_info.style
   you already have an ID column in your style table, but you just try to use "style" filed as a foreign key or else create your style field as your primary key
6. We can use coalesce() instead of using IsNull() , but not a must
7. use getDate() default value for all the possible date fields

Note: If you created all these for testing purposes and if you know all the above, please ignore :).

Below is the query I used and it works for me:

```
SELECT        
    tbl_style_info.buyer, tbl_style_info.style, 
    tbl_style_info.process, @form_date fromdate, sew_rcv_date,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(x.rcv_quantity), 0) 
     FROM sew_floor_receive x
     WHERE x.sew_rcv_date < @form_date
       AND x.section = @section 
       AND x.style = tbl_style_info.style) AS PreviousRecord,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(sew_floor_receive.rcv_quantity), 0) 
     FROM sew_floor_receive 
     WHERE sew_floor_receive.sew_rcv_date = @form_date 
       AND sew_floor_receive.section = @section 
       AND sew_floor_receive.style = tbl_style_info.style) AS TodayRecord
FROM            
    sew_floor_receive 
INNER JOIN
    tbl_style_info ON sew_floor_receive.style = tbl_style_info.style 
                   AND sew_floor_receive.process = tbl_style_info.process 
WHERE 
    sew_floor_receive.sew_rcv_date = @form_date 
    AND sew_floor_receive.section = @section
```

As you can see, I removed the "[tbl_buyer_order_info]" as you did not give it to me.

Comment: It gives me null value. I added table query in upper comment. Can you check and give me a solution. Thanks

Comment: i checked your issue and i found nothing, it works for me

Comment: please check the comments from the new section. if you can provide me with a DB dump, I can try to help you more.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_buyer_order_info](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [buyer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [style] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [order_quantity] [int] NULL,
 [remarks] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [create_time] [datetime] NULL,
 [update_time] [datetime] NULL )

Comment: this is [tbl_buyer_order_info] table